# If I fall, it's said to be instantly - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm found to be on your mind frequently.
>   And you can tip me, respectfully.
>   If I fall, it's said to be instantly.
>   For different roles, you'll adopt me.
>   You'll often tend to wear me out.
>   Or eat me confidently.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> A hat.

I'm found to be on your mind frequently.

> You wear a hat on your head

And you can tip me, respectfully.

> Tip your hat

If I fall, its said to be instantly.

> The expression 'At the drop of a hat' *(Thanks @C.Woods!)*

For different roles, you'll adopt me.

> Different hats are sometimes used to refer to different roles, such as a 'mod-hat' and a 'user-hat' on this site

You'll often tend to wear me out.

> Often you wear a hat outside *(Thanks, @JonathanAllen)*

Or eat me confidently.

> As in the phrase, "I'll eat my hat", said when you're confident about something *(Thanks, @Areeb!)*

Comment: For "if I fall, its said to be instantly" - the expression "at the drop of a hat" means instantaneously or immediately.

Comment: @C.Woods Thanks, I'll edit that in (with a citation)

Comment: Also, "eat me confidently" - people will say "I'll eat my hat" when they are confident that something won't happen. E.g., "if he shows up on time I'll eat my hat."

Comment: Yes, this is it! Good stuff :) You guys are just too clever.

Comment: @C.Woods Areeb got that one already in a suggested edit :)

Comment: I think the "wear out" is that one will often wear a hat when they go outside, rather than being something that wears out (after all doesn't everything?)

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know suggested edits were a thing.